# How do I make this algorithm lazier without repeating myself?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, dry

(Inspired by my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59336641/7509065).)

Consider this code (it's supposed to find the largest element that's less than or equal to a given input):

```
data TreeMap v = Leaf | Node Integer v (TreeMap v) (TreeMap v) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

closestLess :: Integer -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess i = precise Nothing where
  precise :: Maybe (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
  precise closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
  precise closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
    LT -> precise closestSoFar l
    EQ -> Just (k, v)
    GT -> precise (Just (k, v)) r
```

This isn't very lazy. Once the `GT` case is entered, we know for sure that the final return value will be `Just` something rather than `Nothing`, but the `Just` still isn't available until the end. I'd like to make this lazier so that the `Just` is available as soon as the `GT` case is entered. My test case for this is that I want `Data.Maybe.isJust $ closestLess 5 (Node 3 () Leaf undefined)` to evaluate to `True` rather than bottoming. Here's one way I can think to do this:

```
data TreeMap v = Leaf | Node Integer v (TreeMap v) (TreeMap v) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

closestLess :: Integer -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess _ Leaf = Nothing
closestLess i (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
  LT -> closestLess i l
  EQ -> Just (k, v)
  GT -> Just (precise (k, v) r)
  where
    precise :: (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> (Integer, v)
    precise closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
    precise closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
      LT -> precise closestSoFar l
      EQ -> (k, v)
      GT -> precise (k, v) r
```

However, I'm now repeating myself: the core logic is now in both `closestLess` and in `precise`. How can I write this so that it's lazy but without repeating myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use explicit wrappers, you can leverage the type system.  Note that the version of  `precise` that uses `Maybe` for your first code snippet:

```
precise :: Maybe (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
precise closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
precise closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
  LT -> precise closestSoFar l
  EQ -> Just (k, v)
  GT -> precise (Just (k, v)) r
```

is almost exactly the same algorithm as the version of `precise` without `Maybe` from your second code snippet, which could be written in the `Identity` functor as:

```
precise :: Identity (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> Identity (Integer, v)
precise closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
precise closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
  LT -> precise closestSoFar l
  EQ -> Identity (k, v)
  GT -> precise (Identity (k, v)) r
```

These can be unified into a version polymorphic in the `Applicative`:

```
precise :: (Applicative f) => f (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> f (Integer, v)
precise closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
precise closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
  LT -> precise closestSoFar l
  EQ -> pure (k, v)
  GT -> precise (pure (k, v)) r
```

By itself, that doesn't accomplish much, but if we know that the `GT` branch will always return a value, we can force it to run in the `Identity` functor, regardless of the starting functor.  That is, we can start in the `Maybe` functor but recurse into the `Identity` functor in the `GT` branch:

```
closestLess :: Integer -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess i = precise Nothing
  where
    precise :: (Applicative t) => t (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> t (Integer, v)
    precise closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
    precise closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
      LT -> precise closestSoFar l
      EQ -> pure (k, v)
      GT -> pure . runIdentity $ precise (Identity (k, v)) r
```

This works fine with your test case:

```
> isJust $ closestLess 5 (Node 3 () Leaf undefined)
True
```

and is a nice example of polymorphic recursion.

Another nice thing about this approach from a performance point of view is that the `-ddump-simpl` shows that there are no wrappers or dictionaries.  It's all been erased at the type level with specialized functions for the two functors:

```
closestLess
  = \ @ v i eta ->
      letrec {
        $sprecise
        $sprecise
          = \ @ v1 closestSoFar ds ->
              case ds of {
                Leaf -> closestSoFar;
                Node k v2 l r ->
                  case compareInteger i k of {
                    LT -> $sprecise closestSoFar l;
                    EQ -> (k, v2) `cast` <Co:5>;
                    GT -> $sprecise ((k, v2) `cast` <Co:5>) r
                  }
              }; } in
      letrec {
        $sprecise1
        $sprecise1
          = \ @ v1 closestSoFar ds ->
              case ds of {
                Leaf -> closestSoFar;
                Node k v2 l r ->
                  case compareInteger i k of {
                    LT -> $sprecise1 closestSoFar l;
                    EQ -> Just (k, v2);
                    GT -> Just (($sprecise ((k, v2) `cast` <Co:5>) r) `cast` <Co:4>)
                  }
              }; } in
      $sprecise1 Nothing eta
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from my non-lazy implementation, I first refactored `precise` to receive `Just` as an argument, and generalized its type accordingly:

```
data TreeMap v = Leaf | Node Integer v (TreeMap v) (TreeMap v) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

closestLess :: Integer -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess i = precise Just Nothing where
  precise :: ((Integer, v) -> t) -> t -> TreeMap v -> t
  precise _ closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
  precise wrap closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
    LT -> precise wrap closestSoFar l
    EQ -> wrap (k, v)
    GT -> precise wrap (wrap (k, v)) r
```

Then, I changed it to do `wrap` early and call itself with `id` in the `GT` case:

```
data TreeMap v = Leaf | Node Integer v (TreeMap v) (TreeMap v) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

closestLess :: Integer -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess i = precise Just Nothing where
  precise :: ((Integer, v) -> t) -> t -> TreeMap v -> t
  precise _ closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
  precise wrap closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
    LT -> precise wrap closestSoFar l
    EQ -> wrap (k, v)
    GT -> wrap (precise id (k, v) r)
```

This still works exactly as before, except for the benefit of the added laziness.

Comment: Are all those `id`s in the middle between `Just` and the final `(k,v)` eliminated by the compiler? probably not, functions are supposed to be opaque, and you could've (type-feasibly) used `first (1+)` instead of `id` for all the compiler knows. but it makes for a *compact* code... of course, my code is the unraveling and specification of yours here, with the additional simplification (the elimination of the `id`s). also very interesting how the more general type serves as a constraint, a relation between the values involved (not tight enough though, with `first (1+)` being allowed as `wrap`).

Comment: (contd.) your polymorphic `precise` is used at two types, directly corresponding to the two specialized functions used in the more verbose variant. nice interplay there. Also, I wouldn't call this CPS, `wrap` isn't used as a continuation, it's not built up "on the inside", it's stacked - by recursion - on the outside. Maybe if it *were* used as continuation you could get rid of those extraneous `id`s... btw we can see here once again that old pattern of functional argument used as indicator of what to do, switching between the two courses of action (`Just` or `id`).

Answer (score 3):

I think the CPS version you answered with yourself is the best but for completeness here are a few more ideas. (EDIT: Buhr's answer is now the most performant.)

The first idea is to get rid of the "`closestSoFar`" accumulator, and instead let the `GT` case handle all the logic of picking the rightmost value smallest than the argument. In this form, the `GT` case can directly return a `Just`:

```hs
closestLess1 :: Integer -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess1 _ Leaf = Nothing
closestLess1 i (Node k v l r) =
  case i `compare` k of
    LT -> closestLess1 i l
    EQ -> Just (k, v)
    GT -> Just (fromMaybe (k, v) (closestLess1 i r))
```

This is simpler, but takes a bit more space on the stack when you hit a lot of `GT` cases. Technically you could even use that `fromMaybe` in the accumulator form (i.e., replacing the `fromJust` implicit in luqui's answer), but that would be a redundant, unreachable branch.

The other idea that there's really two "phases" of the algorithm, one before and one after you hit a `GT`, so you parameterize it by a boolean to represent these two phases, and use dependent types to encode the invariant that there will always be a result in the second phase.

```hs
data SBool (b :: Bool) where
  STrue :: SBool 'True
  SFalse :: SBool 'False

type family MaybeUnless (b :: Bool) a where
  MaybeUnless 'True a = a
  MaybeUnless 'False a = Maybe a

ret :: SBool b -> a -> MaybeUnless b a
ret SFalse = Just
ret STrue = id

closestLess2 :: Integer -> TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess2 i = precise SFalse Nothing where
  precise :: SBool b -> MaybeUnless b (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> MaybeUnless b (Integer, v)
  precise _ closestSoFar Leaf = closestSoFar
  precise b closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
    LT -> precise b closestSoFar l
    EQ -> ret b (k, v)
    GT -> ret b (precise STrue (k, v) r)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
GT -> let Just v = precise (Just (k,v) r) in Just v
```

?

Comment: Because that's an incomplete pattern match. Even if my function is a whole is total, I don't like pieces of it being partial.

Comment: So you said "we know for sure" still with some doubt. Perhaps that is healthy.

Comment: We do know for sure, given that my second code block in my question always returns `Just` yet is total. I know that your solution as written is in fact total, but it's brittle in that a seemingly-safe modification could then result in it bottoming.

Comment: This will also slightly slow down the program, as GHC can't prove that it will always be `Just`, so it will add a test to make sure it's not `Nothing` every time it recurses through.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do we always know `Just`, *after* its first discovery, we also always know `Nothing` *until* then. That's actually two different "logics".

So, we go left first of all, so make *that* explicit:

```
data TreeMap v = Leaf | Node Integer v (TreeMap v) (TreeMap v) 
                 deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

closestLess :: Integer 
            -> TreeMap v 
            -> Maybe (Integer, v)
closestLess i = goLeft 
  where
  goLeft :: TreeMap v -> Maybe (Integer, v)
  goLeft n@(Node k v l _) = case i `compare` k of
          LT -> goLeft l
          _  -> Just (precise (k, v) n)
  goLeft Leaf = Nothing

  -- no more maybe if we're here
  precise :: (Integer, v) -> TreeMap v -> (Integer, v)
  precise closestSoFar Leaf           = closestSoFar
  precise closestSoFar (Node k v l r) = case i `compare` k of
        LT -> precise closestSoFar l
        EQ -> (k, v)
        GT -> precise (k, v) r
```

The price is we repeat at most *one* step at most once.